# Two return statements in one TypeScript function

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider:

```
export function forbiddenNameValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value)
    return forbidden ? { forbiddenName: { value: control.value } } : null
  }
}
```

From here: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

> The function is a factory that takes a regular expression to detect a specific forbidden name and returns a validator function.

This is a function which returns a ValidatorFn which in turn returns a error or null. 
So, what will get returned actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a example of the reactive form to add a validation. You add **Validators.propertyname**, and if you check the expected type of the second argument, it's a **ValidatorFn** or **ValidatorFn[]** in formcontrol.

So to add a custom validation in this **first return**, there is a return of **ValidatorFn** that can be added in the array.

And the second return is of the logic, when then the validation logic runs then the logic return inside your ValidatorFn run say like a callback or promise behind the scene, so the second return is for that.

```
new FormControl(this.hero.name, [
      Validators.required, --

      forbiddenNameValidator(/bob/i) // <-- Here's how you pass in the custom validator.
    ]),

First place it validation array -->   return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
                               const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);
Second run logic when validation is fired -->   return forbidden ? {'forbiddenName': {value: control.value}} : null;
                             };
```

Simply think about there is inbuilt validation, like   **Validators.required**, and the first you add it in **validation array** that accepts it and then behind the scene when a form value changes, logic written inside this is run and as per the use case the value is returned or an **error variable is set**.

Answer (score 0):

> This is a function which returns a ValidatorFn which in turn returns a error or null.
> So, what will get returned actually?

As you wrote: `forbiddenNameValidator` returns a function that is an instance of `ValidatorFn`.